# How to specify path of libraries in Android.mk file or Application.mk file?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I need to specify the path of library in Application.mk file to link it correctly. How to do this? Is there any GCC command for that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to add `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/path/to/the/library` into the file `Android.mk`.

Comment: I think -L stand for $(LOCAL_PATH)

Answer (score 1):

Add `-L/path/to/the/library` flag to gcc command line parameters.